# how to set top position of scrollbar

Tags: android, scrollview

I insert image in scrollview. and I want to change top position scrollbar.

[image]

I can not find solution.
if you have any solution, please let me know it.

Comment: scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);

Comment: I already applied fullScroll FOCUS_UP. But I don't change top position of scrollbar

Comment: try also scrollView.scrollTo(0, 0);